# Can I run wiring through a plumbing chase?

Tags: electrical, installation, uk

I have a light switch that needs rewiring. Its an old house with brick walls. The existing cable is lead lined and well and truly stuck into position.

I have high ceilings with original plaster coving.

About 18" to the left of the socket around a corner, there is trunking about 5" wide which is taking a couple of hot water pipes upstairs.

I know horizontal chasing is not ideal, but in this case, instead of chasing up my high wall and damaging my coving too, can I be cheeky and chase horizontally into the ducting and run the cables up inside there instead?

Or is this so frowned upon and so dangerous I really shouldn't be considering it?

[image]

Comment: "can I be cheeky and chase vertically into the ducting and run the cables up inside there instead?", not sure of your jurisdiction, but I doubt it would be a valid conduit for your cable.

Comment: Vertical chasing is the *standard* way to do it. You mean chase **horizontally** [blue line] to get into the box section. I'm not keen. It's not so much it running inside the box, so long as you tack it, but the proximity of the hot pipe. Leave a note in the patress box that the cable goes horizontally, if you do. Everybody will expect vertical in an old house. Heck of a job to match that artex though… you could use it as a great excuse to get rid of it all ;)

Comment: I've replaced vertical with horizontal. My bad. Aye, that artex is aaaaaaaall going away. Very soon :D

Comment: AFAIK or remember electrical cables / conduit etc can be vertical or horizontal but NOT diagonal...

Comment: @SolarMike - sure, you *can* chase horizontally if you have to [max 1/6 the total wall thickness]. My worry was more for the pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the UK have surface-mount wire channels something like these from across the pond?

[image: surface mount channel]
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Legrand-Wiremold-700-Series-10-ft-Metal-Surface-Raceway-Channel-in-White-700WH/100144606#overlay

If so, you could try running another channel for wires next to the pipe chase, instead of going into the pipe chase itself.

You might be able to get plastic or rubbery flexible channel which could allow going over the curved wall horizontally then go vertically up the wall, see the new red lines:

[image: horizontal over curve then vertical]

Or if you can go into the wall behind the curve and over to the vertical pipe chase, come out just in front of the chase then go vertical with the channel:

[image: horizontal inside wall then vertical]

In fact, if plastic channel is OK in UK, and you could access behind the wall, then you could run the vertical channel from floor to ceiling, and bring the in-wall wire up into the middle of the channel from underneath along the red dashed line then up, and with appropriate painting the channel will look like it's been there since the house was built and no one will see anything stand out.

Comment: Thank you for the great detail. We do have plastic channelling like that.

Comment: As a FYI: the term in the UK for the thing in this answer is "trunking"